# Find out which ports are forwarded in OS X

Tags: macos, port-forwarding

I want to know if any port of my machine (Mac OSX) is forwarded or not. 
I googled for quite sometime but couldn't find anything for the same. 
There is a network utility which tells which ports are  being used but there is no information about which local port is forwarded to which remote port.

Please let me know if anyone knows of such utility.

Comment: This question should be on [su]

Answer (score 3):

Knowing that is old request, but I had the same question and realised it via:

```
lsof -nP +c 15 | grep LISTEN
```

“lsof” is a contraction for “list open files”. Without any options specifications, lsof lists all open files belonging to all active processes.

“-nP” is a combination of “n” for no resolution of IPs to hostnames using DNS and “P” for no resolution of Port names from numbers.

This is because the command already takes several seconds to run.

“+c 15” specifies command width of 15.

Piping to grep filters out only lines containing “LISTEN”.

[Ports Open on my Mac](https://wilsonmar.github.io/ports-open/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check and see if you have ports open correctly use canyouseeme.org.  Put in the port that you have forwarding set up on and it will tell you if it is open or not.

Comment: I can know wheter a port is opened (used ) or not using utilities like portscan, netstat etc but i want to know whether an opened port is forwarded to some other port on the mac machine.

Answer (score 0):

Port forwarding is probably done by your router check http://portforward.com/ to get help to forward ports on your specific router

Comment: This port is forwarded on a local machine as mentioned in the question and not a router. So portforward.com doesn't help.